# How to match csv stored in one column in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

iam a newbie in mysql

I have stored interests of user in csv format

say person_interests COLUMN stores multiple interests in person TABLE, say

```
$row['person_interests']='11,22,33,44'
```

interests TABLE 11=Music,22=Travel, and so on

Now i want to list all persons who have 11 as interest, what should i use after WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE ????? 
INNER JOIN
interests 
ON 
persons.person_interest
 =
interests.interest_id
WHERE
interest.interest_id=11
```

Comment: Although @Barmar already mentioned it, I want to **emphasize** that it's a bad idea to store multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to store comma-separated data in SQL tables. You should use a many-to-many relation table to hold this. It makes searching and modifying the data more complicated, and matching values can't make use of indexes, so queries will be inefficient.

But if you're stuck with it, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to match them.

```
SELECT *
FROM persons AS p
INNER JOIN interests AS i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.interest_id, p.person_interest)
WHERE i.interest_id = 11
```

Instead of putting all the interests in a single column, you should have a relation table:

```
CREATE TABLE person_interests (
    person_id INT NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to persons table 
    interest_id INT NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to interests table
    UNIQUE INDEX (person_id, interest_id),
    INDEX (interest_id)
);
```

Comment: Thankyou.would you please say why its bad idea to store in CSV ? any good example for storing these kind of data?

Comment: I've added more explanation of why it's a bad idea, and show what you should do instead.

Comment: @tom you should read more about how MySQL works and relational database and you will understand why, what you're doing right now is so bad and inefficient and how you could take more advantage of the database rather than over-thinking difficult ways to get data the way you want out of it.